# Regex to detect words based on the words Action, Object, Sumbject, etc in the middle of a text

Tags: python, regex, nlp

I have the following text and I would like to detect the words after the subject, action and capabilities using regular expressions:

```
For this text:
T1  Subject num num xxx
T2  Action num num  xxx
A1  Capability T2 xxx
```

I have created the following regex but it's not correct:

```
# Regular expressions for pattern matching
action_pattern = r'^T\d+\tAction \d+ \d+\t(.+)$'
subject_pattern = r'^T\d+\tSubject \d+ \d+;?\d+? \d+\t(.+)$'
object_pattern = r'^T\d+\tObject \d+ \d+;?\d+? \d+\t(.+)$'
capability_pattern = r'^A\d+\tCapability T\d+ (.+)$'
```

Comment: "but it's not correct": Details, please.

Comment: @Scott Hunter, see the updated version. As you can see the regex that I have produce a wrong output. Check also the full code that I added. Let me know if you have any idea.

Comment: Why are there no tabs in the target text?

Comment: I couldn't imagine a simpler regex problem. Yet it's obfuscated with output, expected output that does not correlate to anything. Missing output. Missing Tabs in the source. Obfuscated whitespace items in the regex, mixing tabs with spaces as if that has a _direct_ correlation and validation of the forms of the text. These shortcomings make it an easy choice to bypass this one.

Comment: @sln actually the code of Rubisko is working well in my problem. So i think I solved my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I've come up with:

```
text = """
For this text:
T1  Subject 11096 11100 They
T2  Action 11101 11106  steal
A1  Capability T2 007:MalwareCapability-data_theft
T3  Object 11107 11111  data
R1  SubjAction Subject:T1 Action:T2 
R2  ActionObj Action:T2 Object:T3   
T4  Subject 11127 11132;11140 11148 their implants
T5  Action 11152 11156  send
A2  Capability T5 006:MalwareCapability-data_exfiltration
T6  Object 11157 11161  data
T7  Modifier 11162 11168    out of
T8  Object 11169 11180  the network
T9  Modifier 11181 11186    using
T10 Object 11187 11195;11203 11224  a victim network`s mail server
"""
strings = text.split('\n')

action_pattern = r'Action\s[\s;\d]+(.*)$'
subject_pattern = r'Subject\s[\s;\d]+(.*)$'
object_pattern = r'Object\s[\s;\d:]+(.*)$'
capability_pattern = r'Capability\s+T[\s\d:]+(.*)$'

def extract(pattern, strings_lst):
    return [re.search(pattern, string).group(1) 
            for string in strings_lst if re.search(pattern, string)]


print(extract(action_pattern, strings))
print(extract(subject_pattern, strings))
print(extract(object_pattern, strings))
print(extract(capability_pattern, strings))
```

**Output**

```
['steal', 'send']
['They', 'their implants']
['data', 'data', 'the network', 'a victim network`s mail server']
['MalwareCapability-data_theft', 'MalwareCapability-data_exfiltration']
```

You normally don't want to use such congested list comprehensions as in my functions, but for the sake of demonstration and shorter code I did this blasphemy.

*Edit:* Simplified regexes

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! You solved my question that I was stucked for days. One more thing, is it possible for capability to have also the numbers? for example to have '006:MalwareCapability-data_exfiltration', instead of 'MalwareCapability-data_exfiltration'

Comment: @JohnAngelopoulos sure! Assuming the number is always going to be three-digit, you can use the following pattern: `capability_pattern = r'Capability\s+T[\s\d:]+(\d{3}:.*)$'`